# How to sort two-dimensional array in PHP by child element

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have a simple array in my php code:

```
[Users] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => jffswsrdgkdhhkg
                [conf] => 15
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => kwdhssrkgghfdfj
                [conf] => 6
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [id] => khwssfdkrgfjdgh
                [conf] => 14
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [id] => grjshwdkfgfsdkh
                [conf] => 27
            )

    )
```

How do I can sort parent elemnts by child `conf`?
And elements must be in the desc order.
Tried to use ksort and usort - no result.
Thanks for an help.

```
$o = usort($response, function($a, $b) {
    return $a['conf'] <=> $b['conf'];
});
```

Comment: Using ksort and usort gave 'no result', can you show your code?

Comment: ok. just a minute. i'll update

Comment: If you add `print_r($response);` after the usort how does that leave the data?

Comment: The sort seems to work (I flipped the comparision) [Demo](https://3v4l.org/7lNuP) Are you sure you are referring to "Users"?